# NHibernate "Invalid Cast (check your mapping for property type mismatches); setter of System.Object"

Tags: nhibernate

I've been upgrading my NHibernate installation (was still on 1.2!). All has been good until I tried to setup an Interceptor. If I add an Interceptor to the OpenSession() call, then I get this error when trying to load an entity from the DB:

"Invalid Cast (check your mapping for property type mismatches); setter of System.Object"

If there is no Interceptor, this error does not occur.

The Interceptor is very simple, and in fact I pretty much commented out everything in order to test:

```
public class Interceptor : EmptyInterceptor
{
    public override void AfterTransactionBegin(ITransaction tx)
    {            
    }

    public override void AfterTransactionCompletion(ITransaction tx)
    {            
    }

    public override void BeforeTransactionCompletion(ITransaction tx)
    {            
    }

    //public override int[] FindDirty(object entity, object id, object[] currentState, object[] previousState, string[] propertyNames, IType[] types)
    //{            
    //}

    //public override object GetEntity(string entityName, object id)
    //{            
    //}

    //public override string GetEntityName(object entity)
    //{            
    //}

    public override object Instantiate(string entityName, EntityMode entityMode, object id)
    {
        //((EntityBase)entity).Instantiate(entityName, entityMode, id)
        return new object();
    }

    //public override bool? IsTransient(object entity)
    //{            
    //}

    public override void OnCollectionRecreate(object collection, object key)
    {            
    }

    public override void OnCollectionRemove(object collection, object key)
    {            
    }

    public override void OnCollectionUpdate(object collection, object key)
    {            
    }

    public override void OnDelete(object entity, object id, object[] state, string[] propertyNames, IType[] types)
    {
        //((EntityBase)entity).OnDelete(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);
    }

    //public override bool OnFlushDirty(object entity, object id, object[] currentState, object[] previousState, string[] propertyNames, IType[] types)
    //{            
    //}

    public override bool OnLoad(object entity, object id, object[] state, string[] propertyNames, IType[] types)
    {
        //if (entity.GetType().FullName.Equals("EntityBase"))
        //    return ((EntityBase)entity).OnLoad(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);
        //else
            return false;
    }

    //public override NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString OnPrepareStatement(NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString sql)
    //{            
    //}

    public override bool OnSave(object entity, object id, object[] state, string[] propertyNames, IType[] types)
    {
        //return ((EntityBase)entity).OnSave(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);
        return true;
    }

    public override void PostFlush(System.Collections.ICollection entities)
    {            
    }

    public override void PreFlush(System.Collections.ICollection entities)
    {            
    }

    public override void SetSession(ISession session)
    {
    }
}
```

As such I'm totally baffled. Like I said, with the Interceptor it errors on loading and hydrating entities (after the OnLoad event fires), without the Interceptor it's fine. I'm using nHibernate 3.2.0.2001 with .Net4 against SQL Server 2008.

Any help appreciated! Ben

---

Unfortunately I've been unable to progress this issue, I had to switch to Linq-SQL because of this specific problem, and that I couldn't find a solution in the timeframe required to use these templates. Therefore I can't provide any more information at this time.

Comment: can you post the stacktrace? there we can see which code is executed befor the setter throws